# Automatically Create Image Mask Like COCO

Tags: python, opencv

I have an aerial data set with annotations. The images in the data set have more than one object, and many of these objects are very small in size (10X10 px). The coordinates of each object are specified in the annotations file. I would like to train my data set with the Mask RCNN. I need to create a COCO-style masking for each object.

How do I make masking files automatically using the annotations files instead of creating the masking files manually?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions around here. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe you can show some examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with the code in this article. They have created masks from annotations given in a predefined format. You may edit the code to read from your existing annotations and create the mask images.  [Dataturk link](https://medium.com/@dataturks/converting-polygon-bounded-boxes-in-the-dataturks-json-format-to-mask-images-f747b7ba921c)

Comment: A summary of the content of the linked article would be very helpful here.